# Cannot see figures on screen when painting with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

Please, if someone can explain why I see only one line on panel running this code.
When I remove all frame.add() lines below and keep only one, I can actually choose which line to see but how can I see them all?

Here is main method creating JFrame

```
public class Main extends JPanel {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing Board");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    MyLine line1 = new MyLine(70, 100, 120, 150, Color.BLACK);
    MyLine line2 = new MyLine(60, 80, 120, 150, Color.blue);
    MyLine line3 = new MyLine(50, 65, 120, 150, Color.BLACK);
    MyLine line4 = new MyLine(40, 25, 120, 150, Color.blue);
    MyLine line5 = new MyLine(30, 90, 120, 150, Color.BLACK);
    MyLine line6 = new MyLine(20, 130, 120, 150, Color.blue);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.add(line1);
    panel.add(line2);
    panel.add(line3);
    panel.add(line4);
    panel.add(line5);
    panel.add(line6);
    frame.add(panel);
  }
}
```

My line method extends MyShape

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyLine extends MyShape {

 public MyLine(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,Color colorOfLine){
    super(x1, y1, x2, y2, colorOfLine);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(shapeColor);
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
 }
}
```

MyShape extends jpanel

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public abstract class MyShape extends JPanel {
protected int x1,x2,y1,y2;
protected Color shapeColor;
protected MyShape(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,Color colorOfShape) {
    this.x1=x1;
    this.x2=x2;
    this.y1=y1;
    this.y2=y2;
    shapeColor = colorOfShape;
}
```

Comment: *"see only one line"* That's explained in the duplicate Q&A, in that each 'line' is a component. To paint multiple geometric figures such as lines, it is necessary to paint them all in a **single** component (e.g. `JPanel`).

Comment: hello andrew  i read the duplicate post , tried to change my code to include jpanel and than add the figures to it but it fails also please give me more information about the solution. changes mention above all i see in an empty window

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The `DrawOnComponent` examples shows how to paint multiple rectangles on the same panel.

Comment: @camickr has provided a good link. Go through it carefully. If you **still** cannot figure it out from that, post a [mcve] of your best attempt and let me know in a comment. I'll consider reopening the question. And a tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.